# How to send a two-part POST request with curl?

Tags: bash, http, post, curl

I would like to use `curl` to send an HTTP POST request with a *multipart* body, which consists of two parts `part1` and `part2` like this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; 
boundary=v6jSBESHUN0nHdfaw-GnE4zGVcg0OLfL1

--v6jSBESHUN0nHdfaw-GnE4zGVcg0OLfL1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="part1"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

abc
--v6jSBESHUN0nHdfaw-GnE4zGVcg0OLfL1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="part2"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

xyz
--v6jSBESHUN0nHdfaw-GnE4zGVcg0OLfL1--
```

Note that the content of `part1` is `abc` and the content of `part2` is `xyz`. The charset of `part1` is `ascii` and the charset of `part2` is `utf-8`.

I am trying to do it as follows:

```
curl -X POST -F "part1=abc" -F "part2=xyx" http://myhost/mypost
```

Unfortunately it did not do the trick. Besides, I did not find to how specify the charset of `part2`. How would you suggest send this request with `curl` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the type with `;type=`

```
curl -X POST -F "part1=abc" -F "part2=xyx;type=text/plain; charset=utf-8" http://myhost/mypost
```